# Значение выражения "по случаю"

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, значение-слов

***По случаю*** моего дня рождения к нам пришёл Андрей с подарком для меня.

Означает ли выражение "по случаю", что Андрей пришёл случайно и неожиданно?
Или оно не исключает того варианта, что он был приглашён?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В этом предложении устойчивое сочетание **по случаю** можно заменить словом **из-за** (по причине), но никак не словом **случайно**, поэтому оно выступает в значении предлога, а не наречия.

Конечно, это не исключает возможности того, что Андрей пришёл неожиданно для тех, к кому он пришёл. С другой стороны, возможен также вариант, что Андрей был приглашён. В предложении утверждается только, что сам он знал, по какому поводу пришёл.

Answer (score 4):

[**по слу́чаю**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/214916/%D0%9F%D0%BE)
**I** *нареч. качеств.-обстоят. разг.*
**1.** В результате случайно представившейся возможности (о покупке).
*Это не мой костюм. Я купил его по случаю* (А. Гайдар. Школа).

**2.** Употребляется как несогласованное определение.
*По случаю один священник шёл тою дорогою и, увидев его, прошёл мимо* (из притчи).

**II *предлог, с род.***
Употребляется при указании **на причину** какого-либо действия или **на знаменательное событие**, в связи с которым совершается что-либо; в честь чего-либо, в связи с чем-либо.
*— Мы будем сегодня завтракать, или по случаю невесомости всякие там завтраки и обеды целиком отменяются?* (Н. Носов. Незнайка на Луне)

**По случаю** (чего? Р. п.) **моего дня рождения к нам пришёл Андрей с подарком для меня.**
В этом предложении "по случаю" — это предлог (= по поводу, в связи). Причина появления Андрея — Ваш день рождения.
Если бы Андрей пришел (заскочил, забежал, заглянул) случайно, то у него, скорее всего, не было бы подарка для Вас.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, здесь "**случай**" не означает неожиданности, *нельзя определить*, по приглашению ли пришёл гость, предупредил он о визите или зашёл *неожиданно*. *Случаем* встретиться (*поводом*, *основанием* для встречи) был выбран день рождения, который "случается" раз в году. Этим удобным, **подходящим случаем** могли воспользоваться оба товарища (один другого пригласил) или только тот, который зашёл.